# cpanel not saving password

Tags: google-chrome, passwords, cpanel, autofill

I have a problem with Chrome and cPanel and i think all have this problem not just me. The problem is that i cant save the passwords of the Cpanel logins in Chrome. I wanted to ask if there's any kind of extension url like https://domain:2083/?user=domainusername&password=domainpassword

I saw that in some sites you can use this kind of urls and have the boxes of the username and the password filled automatically. Is there a way to do this with cPanel ? If not can anyone tell me how could i save Username and Password of cPanel logins.

p.s. i have 30-40 websites with cPanel to manage that's why it's a bit of a problem to remember all passwords or to keep "copy-pasting" them.

Comment: Just to add, there is a setting in the WHM to allow that, but it is no longer working, there also is an url you can use to go to the legacy login screen that would remember the login (?login_theme=cpanel-legacy), but it doesn't fill them up when you go back to the new login screen. You could bookmark that url I guess.

Comment: this works very well check it out
https://domain.com:2083/login?user=admin&pass=password

where "admin" is the user of the cPanel and "password" is the password

Answer (score 0):

are your activate secure mode as this
[image]
if you use django
add in setting.py in

```
SecurityMiddleware django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware
```

and set

```
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True.
```

and chech if SSL/TLS certificate is instaled in your server from (Manage SSL sites)

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to check whether **javascript** is enbled in your browser also check whether there is any bug for corresponding cPanel version.